# How to populate all the items inside the array instead of newest, in the twig page

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm new on symfony, I'm currently making a shopping cart in symfony. What i need to know is I'm currently passing all the cart items that were purchased by using an array. When i want to show all the items inside the array in the `details.html.twig` page it only shows the newest item.

**the passing array in var_dump**

```
object(AppBundle\Entity\Cart)#188 (2) { 
    ["totalPrice":protected]=> int(1788) 
    ["cartBookItems":protected]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\CartBookItem)#192 (3) { 
            ["bookID":protected]=> int(1) 
            ["quantity":protected]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["name":protected]=> string(12) "Harry Potter"
        } 
        [1]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\CartBookItem)#469 (3) { 
            ["bookID":protected]=> int(2) 
            ["quantity":protected]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["name":protected]=> string(9) "the Beast"
        }
    }
}
```

**only the newest is shown**

[image]

The code in details page

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Total(LKR)</th>
      <th scope="col">Edit Cart</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>{{sessioncart.totalPrice}}</td>
      <td><li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Cart</a></li></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
    </ul>   
    <h2 class="page-header">{{book.id}}</h2>
    <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Category: {{book.bookname}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Category: {{book.category}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Price: {{book.price}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Quantity: {{quantity}}</li>
    </ul>
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="/">Back to Index</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Can someone tell me how to populate all the data in the array in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for book in cartBookItems %}
 here you could pass {{ book.bookID }} for example or {{ book.name }} for example
{% endfor %}
```

Of course be sure you've added the 'cartBookItems' to render it from your controller.

Answer (score 1):

In Twig there's an instruction called "for" that is used to iterate over an array or something similar.
The code will look like this:
`{% for b in cartBookItems %}
         <li>Category: b.category</li>
 {% endfor %}`